# Add new columns to a SQL Server table within a while loop

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, while-loop, alter

```
declare @a int, @min date, @max date,@i int = 0, @columnname nvarchar(max),@b nvarchar(7) = 'aa'
select @min = min([Starting Date]) from [Quantities&Planning]
select @max = max([Finish Date]) from [Quantities&Planning]
set @a  = DATEDIFF(DAY,@min,@max)
while @i < @a
begin
set @i = @i +1
set @b = str(@i)
set @columnname = 'alter table Test1 add ' + @b + ' decimal(18,2) NULL'
PRINT @columnname
exec (@columnname)
end
```

My code does not work as expected. Basically I want to create new columns named as numbers like 1,2,3,4,5... Here is the error code:

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
>   Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
>
> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 11
>   Could not find stored procedure 'alter table Test1 add decimal(18,2) NULL'.
>
> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 11
>   Could not find stored procedure 'alter table Test1 add decimal(18,2) NULL'.
>
> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 11
>   Could not find stored procedure 'alter table Test1 add decimal(18,2) NULL'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **parenthesis** around the `variable` next to `EXEC`

```
...........
exec (@columnname)
...........
```

Alternatively you can `SP_EXECUTESQL` to execute the framed DDL query, which does not require parenthesis but the variable should be of `NVARCHAR` type

```
...........
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @columnname
...........
```

To debug the query you can use `PRINT` statement before executing

```
...........
PRINT @columnname
exec (@columnname)
...........
```

Comment: now it throws this exception:  Msg 173, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The definition for column 'decimal' must include a data type.

Comment: @Macukadam  The variable `@b` is **empty** that why you are getting this error. Make sure `@b` variable has some name in it. use print to debug the query

Comment: alter table Test1 add         decimal(18,2) NULL
Msg 173, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The definition for column 'decimal' must include a data type.
alter table Test1 add         decimal(18,2) NULL
Msg 173, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The definition for column 'decimal' must include a data type.

Comment: @Macukadam - Dude, **@b variable is empty** when you want to add a new column to a table you need to give some name to it

Comment: alter table Test1 add         decimal(18,2) NULL  printing gives something like this. there is a huge space between add and decimal(18,2) btw this are extra questions ofc :) thanks

Comment: I have filled it allready. But when executing it gives very same error above.

Comment: I fixed it.  set @b = str(@i,2,0) it was about my str funcion was wrong from the beginning. Thank you @Prdp